# Pages restricted by login filter are still accessible by other users

Tags: session, jsf-2, servlet-filters

I am using Filters in my login application. I want some pages only
accessed by admin. I have kept those pages in admin folder and
implemented filters in my project. But pages are still accessible
through URL by other users.

Where I am going wrong?

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;


public class LoginFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        // If you have any <init-param> in web.xml, then you could get them
        // here by config.getInitParameter("name") and assign it as field.
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

        if (session == null || session.getAttribute("user") == null) {
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/Login.xhtml"); // No logged-in user found, so redirect to login page.
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res); // Logged-in user found, so just continue request.
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // If you have assigned any expensive resources as field of
        // this Filter class, then you could clean/close them here.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically there are 2 possible reasons for this:

- The filter doesn't run at all
- The filter doesn't protect the pages of the application.

I know it sounds trivially but could you specify whether the filter runs at all, and if yes, do you come to chain.doFilter(req,res) ?

Comment: In above problem  specification i have included all codes related to login except UI... where i am going wrong ??? if filter is not getting executed then what i need to do for correcting it ?

Comment: yes, but did you try to debug this, after all you can debug the filter like any other piece of code. Whats the URL that you're trying to access? You've defined your filter to be applied only for urls starting with admin/... You tell your filter doesn't run at all ? I remember once I've seen that servlets put into the default package are not processed correctly by the Tomcat engine (it was ~ 5 years ago). Please try to put the filter into some package

Comment: After adding filter in another package still i am facing same problem

Comment: http://localhost:8084/project1/faces/admin/details.xhtml this is url i want to restrict from other users

Comment: if so, why does your url-pattern in web.xml contains /admin/? It should be something like /faces/admin/*    right?

Comment: Before Implementing filters i  had kept admin pages directly under Web Pages folder...after implementing filters i created subfolder as admin and moved admin forms to that folder....issue is forms which i have moved are not working correctly... i am not able to submit the form,nor ajax validations getting displayed...what is solution ?

Comment: after making changing like below code ,form in add.xhtml is not working correctly. 



<navigation-case> 
<from-action>#{loginAction.validateUser}</from-action> 
<from-outcome>valid</from-outcome> 
<to-view-id>/admin/add.xhtml</to-view-id> 
</navigation-case>